# CakePHP Authentication login action

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to set up the new Authencation method from CakepHP. When logging in I get the message in debug that the credentials are missing. In the request POST data the email and password fields are submitted. Am I missing something?

```
    /**
     * Login method
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();

        // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
        if ($result->isValid()) {
            $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
            return $this->redirect($redirect);
        }

        // display error if user submitted and authentication failed
        if ($this->request->is(['post']) && !$result->isValid()) {
            $this->Flash->error('Invalid username or password');
        }
    }


public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $service = new AuthenticationService();

        $fields = [
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password'
        ];

        // Load identifiers
        $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', compact('fields'));

        // Load the authenticators, you want session first
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
            'fields' => $fields,
            'loginUrl' => '/users/login'
        ]);

        return $service;
    }
```

EDIT: After editing the Form Authenticator options with the username/post field I get the following

> error: FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND

The SQL debug says the record is found in the Users table.

```
SELECT 
  Users.id AS `Users__id`, 
  Users.email AS `Users__email`, 
  Users.password AS `Users__password`, 
  Users.role AS `Users__role`, 
  Users.created AS `Users__created`, 
  Users.modified AS `Users__modified` 
FROM 
  users Users 
WHERE 
  Users.email = 'my@my.com' 
LIMIT 
  1
```

Users table structure

```
id Primary key  int(11)
email   varchar(255)    utf8mb4_general_ci
password    varchar(255)    utf8mb4_general_ci
role    varchar(255)
created datetime
modified    datetime
```

Comment: So your post data contains the fields `email` and `password`? If so, you also need to configure the `Form` authenticator to use these fields, just like you're doing it with the `Password` identifier.

Comment: Thanks, one step further. Next error is: FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND

Comment: And yes, I have added an USER in the table :)

Comment: Maybe not with the correct data, impossible to tell from here... you'll have to show a little more details (like the user table schema, the user record data, and your post data).

Comment: Still haven't found the solution to last error, updated the original post with addtional information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, had the password in plain text. Added a new user with the default password hasher.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still wondering what you have do.
In my migrations i had this:

```
//In Users Migration 
$table->addColumn('password', 'char', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
```

Change it with this:

```
$table->addColumn('password', 'string', [
        'default' => null,
        'limit' => 255,
        'null' => false,
    ]);
```

And it will work.
You have to set the column type of your password column to character_varying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

A possible very common error is that when defining the fields of the table, the ***password*** field is declared with a small size (10-15 characters) and when using the Authentication component, the password becomes a ***hash*** of a much larger size, so it is recommended to declare the password field with a size of 255 characters and thus avoid inconveniences when trying to log in a user.